# who decide actual storage of register storage class?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, compilation, compiler-optimization, storage-class-specifier

Recently I have been asked following Q in a interview :
Who actually decide that where register variable will be store(in RAM or register).

I have searched on google, the ans I got that compiler decide.
but how can compiler decide ? It should be decided at run time as per my understanding.

what if we compile and run program in different machine , then how can compiler decide where to store register storage class value.

Comment: It's a compile time decision. When you write soomething like this

Comment: register int a, b, c ; a = b+c the compiler has to know where to store the result of a+b. Defer the decision to run time would make code mush slower, and so there will be no gain in using registers

Comment: ok , suppose that compiler decided that store this variable in register , but at run time , there is no register available , so that value will be store in memory , then who decide this ? is it kernel , or process control block ? or something else ?

Comment: It is the optimizer.

Comment: If the compiler allocates a register, how could there not be a register availabe?

Comment: how can compiler know about the register of a remote machine ? what if i just ftp my a.out to some different machine (same OS) , and run there , but compiler has decided about the register of a machine , where program was compiled , then what will happen?

Comment: If you ftp your a.out to a different machine that does not have the architecture that the program was compiled for then the program doesn't work, either with an error message saying "wrong architecture" or "invalid instruction" or it simply crashes or does the wrong thing. There is no machine adaptation mechanism in compiled code.

Comment: can if fail for same platform also , suppose hardware configuration is same , and the os also same ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `register` storage class specifier is a hint to the compiler that accesses to a variable ought to be “as fast as possible”, implying (on register architectures) that its storage should be allocated to a register. This prohibits a few things, like taking the address of the variable—registers don’t have addresses. However, the compiler is free to ignore this hint (§6.7.1¶5):

> A declaration of an identifier for an object with storage-class specifier `register` suggests that access to the object be as fast as possible. The extent to which such suggestions are effective is implementation-defined.

When compiling your code, the compiler must choose how to map local variables and arithmetic operations into operations on CPU registers and stack memory. This is called *register allocation*; these decisions are made at compile time, and baked into the compiled code of a function.

Suppose we have a very naïve compiler that does precisely what we say, and doesn’t optimise anything. If we give it this code:

```
int x;
x = 2;
x += 5;
```

Then we might expect to see this output, on an x86 machine:

```
sub esp, 4          ; allocate stack space for an integer
mov dword [esp], 2
add dword [esp], 5
```

But if we write:

```
register int x;
x = 2;
x += 5;
```

Then we might expect to see:

```
mov eax, 2
add eax, 5
```

The latter is more efficient because it prefers register accesses over memory accesses. In practice, contemporary compilers have intelligent register allocation algorithms that make this storage class specifier unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for explanation Jon,  what will happen if i just ftp my a.out to some different machine (same OS) , and run there , but compiler has taken decision about the register of a machine , where program was compiled, what will if program is running in different machine? That time how it decide to store in register or RAM?

Comment: @pankajkushwaha: If a variable has been assigned to a register by the compiler, then it will be placed in that register on any machine on which you run the code. The architecture (x86, x86-64, ARM, etc.) defines which registers are available—every x86 processor has an `eax` register, for example.

Comment: ok , but what if that remote machine register is already in use , may be by some other programm? ( given that my program was compiled in different machine)

Comment: @pankajkushwaha: It will not be in use. A process has exclusive access to the registers on the processor core where it’s running; the OS scheduler determines how much time to give to each concurrent process, but only one process is running at a time on a given core. This is called [time slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_(computing)#Time_slice).

Comment: Thanks Jon ,I am sorry if its silly ,  but suppose that there is a logic (like if register free) on which compiler take decision that to store in register or store in memory. Now my a.out is running in different machine , where that logic does not hold true(some other process using same register), then program will give some error , or it will manage both value using concept of time slicing?

Comment: @pankajkushwaha: That would never happen. Say you have two processes: your program running in process A and another program running in process B. The OS scheduler will run process A for a while, then stop it, save the state of the registers, then switch to process B, and so on, alternating between A and B. Unless the OS has a bug, A and B will never interfere with each others’ registers.

Answer (score 1):

Several types of optimisations are made by compiler,during compile time and depending upon these optimisations, the request is granted or refused.

> *The third last phase of compilation --- intermediate code generation keeps the basis of generating an intermediate three-address(opcode) based
>   coding,which is further optimised in the second last phase of
>   compiler-optimisation. The last phase of compiler --- `target
>   code generation` makes it guaranteed whether the register storage
>   class variable will be granted the register or not.*

The request of granting register access to the variable is made by the program,but,finally, it is the compiler who decides the allocation of variable's memory in the register depending on :-

1. Availability of registers in the CPU.
2. More stable optimisations,etc.

Comment: ok, I am referring following line: - target
  code generation makes it guaranteed whether the register storage class variable will be granted the register or not. but what will happen if we compile and run program in different machine , suppose that at time of compile there were enough register available , so compile decided that store in register , but when we run programm , there is no free register available , then data will be store in ram , so i mean who decide it run time .... is my understanding wrong?

Comment: @pankajkushwaha- As I already mentioned, it's compiler's job to clear whether variables are going to get stored in registers or not. If the request has been made by the compiler, the register space will be ready to be allocated during compile-time itself. `If the compiler allocates a register, how could there not be a register availabe???`

Comment: Thanks shekhar , I got your point , my only query is what will happen if  i just ftp my a.out to some different machine (same OS) , and run there , but compiler has taken decision about the register of a machine , where program was compiled, what will happen if programm is running in different machine?